# Powershell Script Design - Foreach switch vs Invoke-Command vs Start-Job vs separate scripts altogether

Tags: powershell

This is a design question more so than a technical code question. Please excuse me if this is best suited for another stack exchange community.

I have a large script file that will perform a set of actions for each file in `$SelectedNames` on a daily basis triggered by Windows Task Scheduler. The script is structured like so:

```
# search directory
$directory = 'C:\files'

# list of substrings in file names to look for
$SelectedNames = @('persons', 'activity', 'salesreport', 'syslog', 'dailyresults', 'summary')

# find files matching SelectedNames from today
$Files = Get-ChildItem $directory | Where-Object {

    $v = $_.name
    $t = $_.LastWriteTime.Date

    $SelectedNames | Where-Object { $v.Contains($_) -and $t.Equals((Get-Date).Date) }
}

## process loop

foreach($f in $Files) {

    switch -Wildcard ($f.name)

    {
        '*persons.csv' {
            
            ## do stuff
        }

        '*activity.csv' {

            ## do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

My `$SelectedNames` array contains 20 values and the code block for each match in `switch` is around 50-60 lines (including comments & spacing). I routinely have to maintain code in one of the blocks or add a configuration for another file.

I've been exploring options for how to redesign this script but I'm not sure what the best option is. The actions taken for each file are largely unique, so creating a function to simplify the code isn't really an option. Mainly I am trying to find the best balance between performance and management of the code/actions. I'm not sure if there is a right or wrong answer here so I'm seeking advice from those who have dealt with something similar.

So far I've come up with the following options:

1. Separate out each script block in `switch` to its own `.ps1` file that is called by `Invoke-Command`, accepting the file name as a parameter. This would make the script much shorter by moving the script blocks to their own files but introduce a new layer of complexity with so many additional `.ps1` files.
2. Same as first option but use `Start-Job` instead of `Invoke-Command`. I'm not interested in parallelism so I'd probably use `Start-Job | Wait-Job`. I like this over `Invoke-Command` since I can capture metadata about the job execution in the main script.
3. Scrap the script entirely and create a separate `ps1` script for each file, which would also require a separate Scheduled Task for each process. This will certainly keep everything separate, but might be overkill.

Thank you!

Comment: Even  if the processing for each filename is unique, there's nothing wrong with separating the individual  "case" logic out into 20+ separate functions / files - in an IDE like VS Code it's much easier to navigate between code *files* in the file pane then constantly paging up and down in one giant script. That will help with maintainability because you're separating the file processing logic out from the orchestration logic (i.e. the ```switch```). It also makes the history in source control easier to navigate as you can see which "file processing" files change in each commit...

Comment: @mclayton that's a really going point for navigation and visibility. I'm usually working in isolated ps1 files in their own directories so I don't see them all together like that very often, but very doable. As for your comment "functions / files".. do you have a preference or see a benefit to using one or the other? Calling a file directly vs calling a function that loads a file?

Comment: Unless you have an actual need for metadata(or have a reason to think you might need them at some point in the future), I'd go with one `Invoke-Command` for each `Switch` branch, though a simple `.\ScriptName.ps1` might also work? Anyway it wouldn't really increase complexity much, unless you have a ton of functions\classes shared between said scripts... which would be an even better reason to split them up.